# Solving $x^2+y^2-2z^2 = 0, x^2+2y^2+z^2 = 4$ through $y(x)$ and $z(x)$

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations

How can one show that this equation system

$$x^2+y^2-2z^2 = 0$$

$$x^2+2y^2+z^2 = 4$$

locally at $(1,1,1)$ can be solved through the differentiable functions $y(x)$ and $z(x)$?

I put it in WolframAlpha, but I get weird results and I don't know what the "algorithm" is to solve it through differentiable functions...

Comment: Note the solution of the system is the intersection of an ellipsoid centered in $(0,0,0)$ and a cone parallel to $z$-axis.

Comment: Likely you’re meant to use the implicit function theorem for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ x^2+y^2-2z^2 = 0  \tag 1$$

$$x^2+2y^2+z^2 = 4 \tag 2$$

$2 \times (1) - (2)$ gives
$$x^2-5z^2 = -4 $$

$2 \times (2) + (1)$ gives
$$3x^2+5y^2 = 8 $$

In the neighbourhood of $(1,1,1)$ the intersection can be parametrized as

$$I(x) = \bigg (x, \sqrt{  \frac {8-3x^2}5} , \sqrt{  \frac {4+x^2}5  } \bigg )    $$